# Why does the reputation tab not show in today's lost reputation?

Tags: discussion

I lost 4 reputation points because of downvotes. 4 reputation has been deducted from my total (`it was 1,035`), but it is not showing inside the reputation tab. Below is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: There's a checkbox at the bottom of the page - to show deleted posts.